# GoogleMaps in Mono For Android

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin

I had downloaded 2 samples from *Xamarin*, *GoogleMaps* and *MapsDemo*.

- The **first one**  implements a java class to work with *GoogleMaps* and **works fine** but when i want to manipulate this code, it doesnt work at all.
- The **second one** shows an **error** from the library *mono.Android.GoogleMaps* and says
  `"Assembly not available for Mono for Android 2.2(in Mono2.10)"`, and i was researching through internet and the only thing that i found was that i have to *downgrade to 1.9.2* but i want to work with the latest version, so how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Mono for Android 1.9.2 is the most current version.  There is no such thing as "Mono for Android 2.2".

Comment: but if want to develop with the latest verison how can i do?

Comment: actually today the latest downloadable monodroid version is 2.2 without googlemaps bindings http://android.xamarin.com/